# Rows concatenating while copying data from SQL to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, copy-paste

My SQL query returns 100 rows. When I copy the result to excel sheet or try to download as CSV, data in one of the columns is getting concatenated and excel shows only 30 rows.

For example my query result shows:

```
Id Name Expression
1  aa   One
2  bb   Two
3  cc   Three
4  dd   Four
```

The data in excel sheet gets copied as:

```
  Id Name Expression
    1  aa   One
    3  cc   Two Three Four
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Are there commas in your data?

Comment: No, but there are (% _ @ $ .-)

Answer (score 0):

Right click any database on your SQL Server -> Tasks -> Export Data, a wizard will pop up. Select your source SQL Server and Destination as Flat File Destination, you can just put an empty csv file on your drive, select Format, Text qualifier. follow with the wizard. See what you can get.

Comment: I think i found whats causing issue. It is double quotes. Will this fix that problem ? I have tried CSV, it still cannot handle concatenation.

Comment: In export Wizard, Text qualifier change <none> to double quotes ". By the way, when you open your exported CSV as notepad, how many row are there?

Comment: It just gets messed up after the copy text. So I handled it before copying.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found out that the problem was created by double quotes, I just separated the rows with double quotes.

So we can separate rows, that is first pick all rows with no quotes and then pick all rows with quotes
or 
replace quotes with something else.

```
Select  Id, Name, Case Expression When '"' THEN 'BuggerQuotes' ELSE Expression FROM table1
```

After copying data to excel sheet, I replaced my BuggerQuotes text with double quotes.